# How do I Group By Date and Measure fields to calculate rank?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set with Student Names, the date of transaction and the amount.
Each student has made multiple transactions.

I want to calculate current month rank and previous month rank based on total amount for each student.

I am able to do a group by Student Name to calculate the total amount for each student using:

```
transactions['Totals'] = transactions.groupby('Student Name')['Sale Amount'].transform('sum')
```

How do I extend this to make two different columns that calculate previous month totals and current month totals for each student, so I can assign previous month and current month ranks to them?

The date is in the following format:

```
    09/05/2015 04:18 PM
    07/15/2019 09:50 AM
    05/18/2018 02:34 PM
    08/11/2018 06:29 PM
    06/14/2018 07:42 AM
```

EDIT : Adding dataframe for reference:

```
Out[15]: 
      Date of Transaction       Student Name  Sale Amount
0     09/05/2015 04:18 PM          Dan Kelly         4333
1     07/15/2019 09:50 AM         Peter Dyer         8805
2     05/18/2018 02:34 PM  Natalie Robertson         5640
3     08/11/2018 06:29 PM        Sean Miller         6485
4     06/14/2018 07:42 AM     Thomas Forsyth         6815
                  ...                ...          ...
9977  03/15/2018 09:28 PM        Grace Vance         6379
9978  08/07/2019 11:14 PM  Alexandra Cameron         6688
9979  01/09/2015 10:53 AM  Sebastian Vaughan         2262
9980  05/19/2019 10:00 PM     Caroline Blake         6977
9981  01/11/2016 04:05 AM     Austin Edmunds         3205

[9982 rows x 3 columns]
```

EDIT : Adding sample expected output:

[image]

Comment: are you able to provide a more accurate dataset? with your expectedoutput?

Comment: @Datanovice - The only three columns are the ones I've already mentioned. Student Name, Sale Amount and Date of Transaction. I've added the DataFrame for reference. My expected output is two new columns : Previous Month Rank and Current Month Rank.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(
    df["Student Name"], df["Date"].dt.strftime("%b"), df["Sale Amount"], aggfunc="sum").fillna(0).reset_index()` this should work.

Comment: That gave me a crosstab with discrete months. I guess I will require continuous months to pick data for Current and Previous months in order to calculate ranks.

Comment: Are you able to provide your intended output ? it would be much easier to provide a solution if so.

Comment: @Datanovice - Please refer to my comments on powerPixie's answer. It is difficult for me to give you a visual representation of my expected output.

Comment: What defines the current month?

Comment: The month of the latest transaction in the data since I do not know if the client will update the data each month.

Comment: hmm, it's hard to say without seing a visual rep, if you can't provide that it's hard to provide a solution

Comment: Basically, the original data remains at a transactional level, but the two new columns we add are going to be at a higher level of detail. (For a particular Student Name, all rows in new column one should have the rank based on the total sales in previous month, for eg- if he did the most sales, each row in this column will have 1. Similarly, for the second new column all rows will have the rank based on total sales in current month, for eg- if he did the second most sales this month, all rows will have 2. This will be partitioned at every new Student Name.) Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

I've created a dataframe with the minimal data you informed: 'Student Name', 'Sale Amount', 'Date'

My dataframe:

```
          df = pd.DataFrame([['12/05/2019 04:18 PM','Marisa',500],
               ['11/29/2019 04:18 PM','Marisa',500],
               ['11/20/2019 04:18 PM','Marisa',800],
               ['12/04/2019 04:18 PM','Peter',300],
               ['11/30/2019 04:18 PM','Peter',300],
               ['12/05/2019 04:18 PM','Debra',400],
               ['11/28/2019 04:18 PM','Debra',200],
               ['11/15/2019 04:18 PM','Debra',600],
               ['10/23/2019 04:18 PM','Debra',200]],columns=['Date','Student Name','Sale Amount']
               )
```

Be sure date is a datetime column.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

This gives you the total amount per month per student in the original dataframe:

```
df['Total'] = df.groupby(['Student Name',pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M')])['Sale Amount'].transform('sum')


    Date Student             Name       Sale Amount  Total
0 2019-12-05 16:18:00       Marisa          500      500
1 2019-11-29 16:18:00       Marisa          500     1300
2 2019-11-20 16:18:00       Marisa          800     1300
3 2019-12-04 16:18:00        Peter          300      300
4 2019-11-30 16:18:00        Peter          300      300
5 2019-12-05 16:18:00        Debra          400      400
6 2019-11-28 16:18:00        Debra          200      800
7 2019-11-15 16:18:00        Debra          600      800
8 2019-10-23 16:18:00        Debra          200      200
```

How to print only the selected results?

df is dnew now:

```
dnew = df
```

Let's strip datetime to keep months only:

```
#Strip date to month
dnew['Date'] = dnew['Date'].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%m'))
```

Drop Sale Amount entries and group by Student Name and Date (new dataframe is "sales"):

```
#Drop Sale Amount 
sales = dnew.drop(['Sale Amount'], axis=1).groupby(['Student Name','Date'])['Total'].max()


print(sales)
Student Name  Date
Debra         10       200
              11       800
              12       400
Marisa        11      1300
              12       500
Peter         11       300
              12       300
```

Actually, "sales" is pandas.core.series.Series and it's important to know that

```
print(sales.index)
MultiIndex([( 'Debra', '10'),
        ( 'Debra', '11'),
        ( 'Debra', '12'),
        ('Marisa', '11'),
        ('Marisa', '12'),
        ( 'Peter', '11'),
        ( 'Peter', '12')],
       names=['Student Name', 'Date'])    

 from datetime import datetime      
 curMonth = int(datetime.today().strftime('%m')) #transform to integer to perform (curMonth-1)
 #12

 #months of interest
 moi = sales.iloc[(sales.index.get_level_values('Date') == str(curMonth-1)) | (sales.index.get_level_values('Date') == str(curMonth))]

 print(moi)

 Student Name  Date
 Debra         11       800
               12       400
 Marisa        11      1300
               12       500
 Peter         11       300
               12       300
```

Comment: This makes sense. But how do I extend this to create two new columns, Previous Month Rank and Current Month Rank?

Comment: @NickAdams, I've edited my answer to show you a possible solution for your new question. It starts at "How to print only the selected results?"

Comment: This works well, but it a little different from my expected output. Two points : 1) Will this still work if my data has transactions from a lot of previous years? Will it adjust to the latest month present in the data or is it using system date to calculate current and previous months? 2) I need to visualize this data in Tableau and would like to keep the original rows. Is it possible to create two new columns instead that hold the current and previous month ranks based on sales in those months? (Or even the sale amounts that you calculated, if not ranks)

Comment: 1) Do you need the previous years? If you don't you can clean or fiter the data. You said you wanted current month and previous month, if you pay attention to the code I used datetime.today(). It means system datetime. 2) If you want to add the two new rows, it's more like the first solution I  gave you, because you will always have sales amount (Sale Amount) column.

Comment: I need the original dataset with historical data (previous years) to do analysis like trends and totals. The ranking system is another analysis which will only be based on previous month and current month sales. Ideally, I do not want to create two different versions of the same dataset for these two analyses. I know it can be done in the same dataset, just do not know how. The best I can think of is the approach of adding two new columns with previous and current month ranks which will run at a higher level of detail. This will ensure that I can use one modified dataset for both analyses.